# how to disconnect client in angular-socket-io using socket.conn.id?

Tags: websocket, socket.io

is there another way to disconnect by `socket.conn.id` besides `socket.clients[kickedUserSocketId].onDisconnect();`
in btford's angular-socket-io? calling `socket.disconnect()` after checking for id or username seems rather the improper way of disconnecting client.